# TWRP image installation issue

Tags: android, adb, fastboot

I am trying to install custom recovery in my Realme X50 pro 5G device. I had downgraded it's Android version from 12 to 10. I have unlocked the bootloader. Now the last step is to replace the default bootloader by the TWRP. Here I am facing issue.

This command worked.

`>>> fastboot flash recovery rec.img`

```
sending 'recovery' (131072 KB)...
OKAY [  3.350s]
writing 'recovery'...
OKAY [  0.516s]
finished. total time: 3.872s
```

But this command is not working.

`>>> fastboot boot recovery.img`

```
OKAY [  3.116s]
booting...
FAILED (remote: unknown command)
finished. total time: 3.130s
```

Someone please help me to solve the issue.

Comment: You might want to ask on XDA or so.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski sure lemme do